# How to compress rows to a binary list in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a list of page visits by session id.  I need to modify that to be a list of two pages each, repeating across the list until they are all used.  The ID would be duplicated down the new rows.  I also need to keep the prior node to go with the new one.

I want to turn this:

```
Session Page
ID1     Home
ID1     Inventory
ID1     Details
ID1     Home
ID2     Inventory
ID2     Home
ID2     Details
ID2     Inventory
ID3     Inventory
ID3     Details
ID4     Details
ID4     Inventory
ID4     Details
ID4     Inventory
ID4     Details
ID4     Inventory
ID4     Details
ID4     Inventory
ID4     Home
```

Into this:

```
Session Node1       Node2
ID1     Home        Inventory
ID1     Inventory   Vehicles
ID1     Vehicle     Home
ID2     Inventory   Home
ID2     Home        Vehicle
ID2     Vehicle     Inventory
ID3     Inventory   Vehicle
ID4     Vehicle     Inventory
ID4     Inventory   Vehicle
ID4     Vehicle     Inventory
ID4     Inventory   Vehicle
ID4     Vehicle     Inventory
ID4     Inventory   Vehicle
ID4     Vehicle     Inventory
ID4     Inventory   Home
```

The ultimate goal is to feed this into igraph to do a network diagram of the activity.  There can be as many as 44 different page visits in a session if that is meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Vehicle is Details, and your data is stored in `mydata`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, Node2 := Page[.I + 1]]
mydata[, t := Session[.I + 1]]
mydata[Session == t, list(Session,Node1 = Page,Node2)]
```